# How can I inherit methods for a struct containing another one

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am from C++ background and very new to rust. I have the following code which I have written to understand the code reusability, which is the sole purpose behind inheritance.

```rust
/* in animal.rs */
//declare Animal here
pub struct Animal;

// implement Animal here
impl Animal
{
    pub fn breathe(&self)
    {
        println!("All animals breathe!");
    }
}

// declare Dog here
pub struct Dog 
{
    pub parent: Animal
}

// implement Dog here
impl Dog
{
    pub fn bark(&self)
    {
        println!("Dogs bark!");
    }
    pub fn breathe(&self)
    {
        self.parent.breathe();
    }
}

/* in main.rs */
mod animal;

fn main() 
{
    let d = animal::Dog {parent : animal::Animal};
    d.bark();
    d.breathe();
}
```

If I don't implement the `breathe` function in `Dog` the compiler doesn't find it. In C++ the child inherits the functions from its parent. Can someone explain it?

Additional question: Can someone show some example code how dynamic/late binding works in `rust`. In C++ it is achieved by `virtual` functions.

Comment: Reusability is not the sole purpose behind inheritance. Inheriting for code reuse is usually a mistake.

Comment: `parent` is a member variable of `Dog` – there is no inheritance here (or in Rust at all). Read the [Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/).

Comment: It's one of those concepts that C++ programmers usually struggle with for a while. There are many programming patterns that avoid code reuse; inheritance is only one of them. I mean, it works in C, and C is very limited in its feature set. For Rust, C++ programmers have to un-learn the inheritance pattern and instead learn Rust compatible alternatives. Trust me, it works well, it just takes a while to understand that alternatives exist and are very viable. I hope this doesn't discourage you from giving Rust a chance, trust me, it's worth it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no struct inheritance in Rust but you can use trait like in the following example to define a shared behavior. And you can see `dyn AnimalTrait` keyword which is used for dynamic dispatch in Rust.

```
trait AnimalTrait {
    fn is_canine(&self) -> String {
        return String::from("canine");
    }
}

pub struct Dog;
impl AnimalTrait for Dog {}

pub struct Cat;
impl AnimalTrait for Cat {}

pub struct Mouse;
impl AnimalTrait for Mouse {
    fn is_canine(&self) -> String {
        return String::from("not canine");
    }
}

fn main() {
    let (d, c, m) = (Dog {}, Cat {}, Mouse {});

    let all_animals: Vec<Box<dyn AnimalTrait>> = vec![Box::new(d), Box::new(c), Box::new(m)];

    for e in all_animals {
        match e.is_canine().as_str() {
            "canine" => println!("I can tear apart well."),
            "not canine" => println!("I will have hard time tearing apart."),
            _ => (),
        }
    }
}
```